# Getting role from .NET core API in the formal " ["Admin"] ". How do i convert it into string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reactjs, .net-core

I am setting the role in react js in local storage and it is being set like this

Key is role and value is ["Admin"].

When I try to get the value it gets in the format "["Admin"]" and therefore I am not able to check the roles.

Here is my backend code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser([FromBody]Models.LoginUserVM model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalide Login Attempt");
            }
            var uId = from s in context.AspNetUsers
                     where s.Email == model.Email
                     select s.Id;

            var rId = from s in context.AspNetUserRoles
                      where uId.Contains(s.UserId)
                      select s.RoleId;

            var rName = from s in context.AspNetRoles
                         where rId.Contains(s.Id)
                         select s.Name;


            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error with email or password");
            }

            if (rName.Contains("Admin"))
            {
                return Ok(rName);
            }
            if (rName.Contains("User"))
            {
                return Ok(rName);
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

[image]

This is how the value is stored in the database.

Help me out if anyone have implemented it or suggest any other way to do it.

Comment: Like it: `value.slice(2, -2);` In your case: `Object.role.slice(2, -2);` will return `"Admin"` only.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks. But this is for particular Admin only what if there are different roles like User, etc

Comment: It will work in all scenarios where the array has only a single element. Like: `"["Admin"]"` or `"["User"]"`.

Comment: @RohitSharma It worked for other roles also. Thank you so much.